# paypal add to cart change price on amount ordered

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

I am putting together a standard "add to cart" button for paypal standard payments (paypay handles processing etc) using a form like so...

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="IDtest" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="19.99" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
```

The price changes if a customer purchases four items or more. Is there a way to integrate the price change into one button, or do I need to use two separate buttons for the different prices?

The buttons will contain dynamic fields for the item name and prices taken from a database. I have two fields relating to the price set up - the original price, and the discount price.